# Remove decimal from fractionalized seconds (SQL from an ODBC connector)

Tags: sql, timestamp, odbc, seconds

Done a lot of searching for an answer and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Here's my query...

```
SELECT 

    {fn TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_SECOND,{fn CONVERT(MyTime,SQL_FLOAT)}*3600,MyDate)}

FROM 
    MyTable
```

And here's what it returns...

```
2009-07-31 15:09:21.000
2009-07-09 11:30:26.000
2009-07-10 13:29:07.000
2009-07-31 15:09:21.000
2009-07-09 11:30:26.000
2009-07-10 13:29:07.000
2009-08-05 15:42:07.000
2009-07-09 11:30:26.000
2009-07-10 13:29:07.000
2009-07-09 11:30:16.000
```

I need to remove the decimal from the seconds in a way that's supported by an ODBC connector. Sadly I've little to no experience working with SQL in this manner.

FYI, *MyTime* is a fractionalized hour, originally a VARCHAR hence the float conversion, which I'm simply multiplying by 3600 to get it in seconds.

edit: It's a ProvideX ODBC driver, PVX Plus

Thanks!

Comment: *"... I've little to no experience working with SQL in this manner."* – There are many different dialects of SQL, each with their own peculiarities. '2009-07-09 11:30:16.000' looks like the *default string representation* of a Microsoft SQL Server `datetime` value, in which case you can simply format that value any way you like in the presentation layer of your application. Generally speaking, SQL is for *extracting* data, not *formatting* it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with formatting it for presentation. Whatever's going on in the back end of the application's ODBC connector doesn't like the fractionalized seconds. I need to remove it so the field can be processed in the first place.

Comment: So if it is ostensibly a driver issue then what driver are you using?

Comment: It's a ProvideX ODBC driver, PVX Plus

Comment: [This code](https://pastebin.com/aaEeyN4V) works for me with Microsoft's *ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server*, which is about as close to a "reference implementation" of an ODBC driver as one could hope for. If it doesn't work for you then you may want to [ask PVX Plus for help](https://home.pvxplus.com/pgsrvr.pvp?pg=support).